# Python Request POST - Upload file via JOOMLA Community Builder Import

Tags: python, joomla, upload

I have a JOOMLA 3 system with Community Builder plugin. I need to update Users from a CSV file.
Here is the code I have tried:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = fn_login()
    r = s.get(cb_users)
    print(r)
    with open(IMPORT_FILE, 'rb') as f:
        files = {'files': f}
        r = s.post(post_url, files=files)
```

The session is ok.  I have tried to figure out the POST message, but something may be missing. Nothing happens when I send the post. I have got response 200. What else do I need to consider?

Here is the request header:
curl 'https://3joomla.domain/administrator/index.php' 
-X 'POST' 
-H 'authority: 3joomla.domain' 
-H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' 
-H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hu;q=0.8' 
-H 'cache-control: max-age=0' 
-H 'content-length: 6710' 
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryALBLy00y6zolw7hC' 
-H 'cookie: .... 
-H 'origin: https://3joomla.domain' 
-H 'referer: [https://3joomla.domain/administrator/index.php'](https://3joomla.domain/administrator/index.php%27) 
-H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"' 
-H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' 
-H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' 
-H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' 
-H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' 
-H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' 
-H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' 
-H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' 
-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' 
--compressed

Comment: Maybe try asking on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Here is the entry: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/32769/import-com-users-via-joomla-community-builder-python-script